# Using "read" for unknown number of inputs in variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im new to bash scripting and I'm trying to write a script that asks for filenames and puts them into a variable (for use in an AWS CLI get from Glacier, but that's not important yet).

I want it to be able to read any number of filenames put onto the same line, separated by a space or other delimiter. I can use read to turn multiple inputs into multiple variables, like

read $variable1 $variable2

but only if I know how exactly how many inputs. How do I do it for any number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From `help read`:

```
  -a array  assign the words read to sequential indices of the array
        variable ARRAY, starting at zero
```

...

```
read -a someArray
```